# make a switch for ids with a click event using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-video

I have a simple block which contains two video elements, I have a pause button I want when user click pause button it pauses the current playing video.

Unfortunately my method is not working. What am I doing wrong in my code?

```js
document.querySelector("#video-pause_btn").addEventListener('click', function() {
  console.log(($(this).attr('id')))
  switch ($(this).attr('id')) {
    case 'video-player_not-transformed':
      pauseVideo();
      break;
    case 'video-player_transformed':
      pauseTransfromedVideo();
      break;
  }
});

var pauseVideo = function() {
  var videoNotTransformed = document.querySelector('#video-player_not-transformed');
  videoNotTransformed.pause();
};

var pauseTransfromedVideo = function() {
  var videoTransformedID = document.querySelector('#video-player_transformed');
  videoTransformedID.pause();
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="video-container">
  <div class="video-container_details">
    <div id="video-pause_btn" class="video-btn">
      <img src="images/stop.png" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="video-conatiner_datavideo">
    <video class="videoplayer" id="video-player_not-transformed">
      <source src="videos/explainer.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
  </div>
  <div class="video-container_transformed">
    <video id="video-player_transformed" style="width: 300px; height:auto; padding: 30px;">
      <source src="videos/transformed.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
  </div>
```

Comment: Your `switch` logic is broken as `$(this).prop('id')` will only ever return `video-pause_btn` because that's the element you've assigned the event handler to

Comment: so what do I need to change to get what I want if you could help?

Answer (score 0):

Your switch logic is broken as `$(this).prop('id')` will only ever return `video-pause_btn` because that's the element you've assigned the event handler to.

A better approach would be to determine which video is currently being played, by using `filter()`, and then pausing it and starting playback of the other video, something like this:

```js
var $videos = $('video');

$('#video-pause_btn').on('click', function() {
  var $playing = $videos.filter(function() {
    return !this.paused;
  }).get();

  if ($playing.length === 0) {
    $videos.first()[0].play();
  } else {
    $playing[0].pause();
    $videos.not($playing)[0].play();
  }
});
```

```css
video {
  width: 250px;
  height: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="video-container">
  <div class="video-container_details">
    <div id="video-pause_btn" class="video-btn">
      Play/pause
      <img src="images/stop.png" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="video-conatiner_datavideo">
    <video class="videoplayer" id="video-player_not-transformed">
      <source src="https://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
  </div>
  <div class="video-container_transformed">
    <video id="video-player_transformed">
      <source src="https://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
  </div>
</div>
```